# Receiving "No Error" from perror(), when a socket has failed to bind

Tags: c, sockets, error-handling, network-programming

I'm following the code step by step from the page,

http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html

But rather than creating two different executable files, I'm trying to integrate them into one application which acts both as a client and a server. But when I call the bind method, it returns a value of -1, so according to the code the application closes. However, perror() simply prints out "bind: No error"

The snippet of code causing this is:

```
     if (bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *) &addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
      perror("bind");
      exit(1);
     }
```

Entering the if case would clearly add an error to the error stack, but the perror method states that there is no error. Do I need to import an additional library of some sort to get the full effect of perror?

Comment: Try to compile with `-D_REENTRANT`.

Comment: What does 'ass an error the error stack' mean, if anything?

Comment: sorry, I've edited the question now, maybe something else was on my mind when I was writing this question :P

Comment: Well there is no such thing as 'the error stack'. There is a single `errno` variable, or a per-thread variable if you're compiling with threading enabled, which you should be.

Comment: The POSIX specification for [`bind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html) doesn't leave much room for wriggling when it says _Upon successful completion, bind() shall return 0; otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error._  If `errno` is zero after the failure, then the implementation is flying against the specification.  You've not shown the declaration of `addr` or how you've initialized it, but that's about the only way things could be going wrong that I can see.  And even then, EINVAL would be at least semi-plausible as an error.

Comment: Are you planning to run two copies of the same program, once as client, once as server, or are you planning a multithreaded program that has one thread acting as client and another thread acting as server?